# Division positioning

Tags: html, image, css

The html is given below

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
}

#cf {
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  height: 360px;
  width: 640px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}

#cf img {
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="cf">
        <img class="bottom" src="http://placehold.it/640x360" />
        <img class="top" src="http://placehold.it/640x360" />
    </div><!--
 --><div id="cf">
        <img class="bottom" src="http://placehold.it/640x360" />
        <img class="top" src="http://placehold.it/640x360" />
    </div><!--
 --><div id="cf">
         <img class="bottom" src="http://placehold.it/640x360" />
         <img class="top" src="http://placehold.it/640x360" />
    </div><!--
 --><div id="cf">
         <img class="bottom" src="http://placehold.it/640x360" />
         <img class="top" src="http://placehold.it/640x360" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The background is properly aligned but the images are offset . What have i done wrong ? Why is the image not being positioned properly?
All the images used are of the dimension 360px height and 640px width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images are offset because you are using `text-align: center` on the container which means that the origin for your positioned child elements is no longer `0 0`, but `50% 0` (centre top):

```
.container {
  ...
  text-align:center;
}
```

To get around this you just need to override this for the child elements:

```
#cf {
  ..
  text-align: left;
}
```

Demo below

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
}

#cf {
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  height: 360px;
  width: 640px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

#cf img {
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div id="cf">
                <img class="bottom" src="http://placehold.it/640x360" />
                <img class="top" src="http://placehold.it/640x360" />
            </div><!--
         --><div id="cf">
                <img class="bottom" src="http://placehold.it/640x360" />
                <img class="top" src="http://placehold.it/640x360" />
            </div><!--
         --><div id="cf">
                <img class="bottom" src="http://placehold.it/640x360" />
                <img class="top" src="http://placehold.it/640x360" />
            </div><!--
         --><div id="cf">
                <img class="bottom" src="http://placehold.it/640x360" />
                <img class="top" src="http://placehold.it/640x360" />
            </div>
</div>
```

But your HTML is invalid. `ID`s must be unique. You should be using a `class` for your `cf` element like so...

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
}

.cf {
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  height: 360px;
  width: 640px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.cf img {
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.cf img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="cf">
                <img class="bottom" src="http://placehold.it/640x360" />
                <img class="top" src="http://placehold.it/640x360" />
            </div><!--
         --><div class="cf">
                <img class="bottom" src="http://placehold.it/640x360" />
                <img class="top" src="http://placehold.it/640x360" />
            </div><!--
         --><div class="cf">
                <img class="bottom" src="http://placehold.it/640x360" />
                <img class="top" src="http://placehold.it/640x360" />
            </div><!--
         --><div class="cf">
                <img class="bottom" src="http://placehold.it/640x360" />
                <img class="top" src="http://placehold.it/640x360" />
            </div>
</div>
```